# Want to add elements into map java

Tags: java

My Question was

Write a program to collect and store all the cards to assist the users in finding all the cards in a
given symbol.

This cards game consist of N number of cards. Get N number of cards details from the user and store
the values in Card object with the attributes symbol and number.

Store all the cards in a map with symbol as its key and list of cards as its value. Map is used here to
easily group all the cards based on their symbol.

Once all the details are captured print all the distinct symbols in alphabetical order from the Map.
For each symbol print all the card details, number of cards and their sum respectively.

My Solution to the above problem was .

```
import java.util.*;
public class CollectCards {
    protected ArrayList<Integer> array;
    protected Map<String,ArrayList<Integer>> card;
    public CollectCards(){
        this.array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        this.card = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>>();
    }
    public void addCard(String name,int number) {
        if(this.card.containsKey(name)) {
             this.card.get(name).add(number);             
        }else {
            this.array.add(number);
            this.card.put(name,this.array);
       }
    }
    public void display(){
       for(Map.Entry<String,ArrayList<Integer>> card : this.card.entrySet()){
          System.out.println(card.getKey()+"\t"+card.getValue());
       }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       CollectCards card = new CollectCards();
       do{
        System.out.println("Enter the card details");
        card.addCard(input.next(),input.nextInt());            
        System.out.println("Want to repeat again!!!");
    }while(input.next().equals("Yes"));
    card.display();
  }
 }
```

Input:

```
s 1
s 2
s 3
s 4

n 1
n 2

m 1
```

output should be :

```
 s -> [1,2,3,4]
 n -> [1,2]
 m -> [1]
```

Output I got for the above program :

```
 s -> [1,2,3,4]
 n -> [1,2,3,4]
 m -> [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: You are allways working on the same instance of the `ArrayList`. you need to have a single ArrayList instance per Map key

Comment: You need to put forth more effort and be more specific. "Here is homework, here is what I got" is not enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot @KevinEsche. I got the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn something about lenguages, like JAVA.

Exist some languages that **pass his vars by reference** that means, you pass a reference to the object not the object instead so, when you do:

```
ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
map.add(1, array);

array.add(1)
```

you are modifiying both of the arrays, your array, and the array in the map, because the map have the reference to the object not a new object, you are working with the same object only referenced in two different places.

So the answer is: everityme you need a new array you need a new Instance:

```
new ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the method `addCard` to this code.

```
public void addCard(String name,int number) {
    if(this.card.containsKey(name)) {
         this.card.get(name).add(number);             
    }else {
        ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>(1);
        this.card.put(name,newList);
   }
}
```

The problem you are facing is that you are basicly putting the same reference to an ArrayList to every single key you are putting into the HashMap.

What you are actually trying to do is to have different ArrayList for each key.
As a result you wont need the  `array` variable anymore